# No password hashes loaded in JohnTheRipper

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-keys, ctf

I'm trying to crach ssh password with **john**, but there's an error, and I can't find the answer to solve it

firstly I use **ssh2john.py**:

```
python3 ssh2john.py id_rsa > id_rsa.hash
```

then **john**:

```
john --wordlist=/usr/wordlists/rockyou.txt id_rsa.hash
```

the result is:

```
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

some people say I need to write format like `--format=crypt`, but it also doesn't work

maybe I need to write another format... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to get John from its github. /run gives all of John tools (i.m. ssh2john etc) and John itself.

so DO NOT do just

```
apt install john
```